# Is this domain name idea suitable for companies, business men & sellers social network?

Tags: user-behavior

I am not 100% sure that this is a question for here but I guess it is related to UX. If, not sorry for this, where should I post it?

I currently own the domain name iBuy with TLD my country's domain. The same name will be the name of the web site that is a **business men & sellers social network. Companies, business men and sellers will have the ability to create their business/professional profile, list products and services, post articles/messages, participate in communities and other stuff.**

My questions are if my choice is suitable for the purpose of the site and if users/business men/sellers will react possitive, familiar and comfortable with the name iBuy?

**UPDATE**

Having in mind your answers I agree my name is really wrong. I thought of the something that will include the word "**Firm**"

taken from *dictionary.com*

- securely fixed in place.
- not shaking or trembling; steady: a firm voice.
- not likely to change; fixed; settled; unalterable: a firm belief.
- steadfast or unwavering, as persons or principles: firm friends.
- indicating firmness or determination: a firm expression.

Comment: I have to say I think the .biz domain has always seemed a bit cheap to me and I very infrequently visit a .biz website. I feel some of that aversion translates to biz in the company name as well as the domain.

Comment: @Roger Attrill I have never visited a .biz site yet. I agree with you, maybe this is how it feels cheap. P.S. I changed the whole concept of my question to a more specific one.

Comment: @ChrisF Thank you for this, I thought that a better structured answer will get more feedback.

Comment: FWIW, this is absolutely a part of UX, and one that is sometimes neglected.

Comment: How can we know if we're not the target audience? **Ask them**. That's the only way you'll find out.

Comment: This is really a marketing/branding question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO - no. There are two things that the iBuy suggest to me, and neither of these are related to a social network of the sort you are defining.

The first is that i-prefixes suggest Apple influenced sites - not necessarily just apple places, but something that relates to apple products and services.

The second is that Buy suggests an e-commerce site, which it isn't. So I would suggest that you use another domain.

Comment: Can you suggest me some terms that may be suitable for all user groups, or at least some of them? I mean like a guideline.

Comment: Starting with You might work ( I know youtube might be similar, but with care it can be done ). And a word implying meeting or talking. YouMeet might work - but the terminology  needs to be client specific.

Comment: Hi again, I have updated my question with a new name, may I have your opinion please?

Comment: As a starter, FirmMeet, for example may be a possibility, or something similar to that. It does have the correct connortations or something solid and something business-related. You need to get the "meeting" word correct too. And avoid any dangerous innuendoes.

Comment: Thank you for this... One last thing though. In the case that the word "firm" was available, will you still prefer something like "FirmMeet" or the word by itself?

Comment: Something with it. Verb and noun - who and what - is easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a good name. The obvious comparison with Apple that people will draw from the i-prefix makes your first impression the thought of something that is not what you do, and someone else's company. While you might be able to legally hold onto iBuy, you'll never own the mindshare from Apple and that hurts the name a lot.

The name could be re-thought to more directly describe what your service will do. Another approach is a name that captures the benefit or the outcome of what you are trying to do. If I had any naming guideline, it would be that. Good luck!

Comment: Hi again, I have updated my question with a new name, may I have your opinion please?

Comment: Firm and the meanings that you described in your update seem like a better direction for finding a name. I'll add to the list of meanings the sense of 'a firm handshake' being a positive thing. You may come across a good name that includes the word firm, but be willing to let that concept guide your thinking, and explore related words.